# Editing fonts in emf file within PowerPoint

Tags: svg, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a bunch of **emf** files that were converted from **svg** files with Inkscape commandline. The SVG files were autogenerated and have text objects. Within an SVG file, the text is nicely editable. For example in Incscape I can directly edit the text, add characters etc.

After converting to emf (since I believe PowerPoint has no support for SVGs) I am trying to embed these emfs on a slide. However, while the shapes are nicely editable (colors, size etc.), the text is very cumbersome to edit. Every letter is separately drawn as a new shape. This makes quick editing very cumbersome, e.g. correcting a typo.

**Is there a solution to have the text editable as a text object itself or all emf files subject to becoming small path objects within PowerPoint exports?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer: Saving "as EMF" in Inkscape has numerous options. One of them is "Convert text to paths". Disable it and get perfectly editable texts - at least if the saved EMF is reopoened in Inkscape. I do not have PowerPoint, so I do not know, if PPt splits your texts to separate letters when you import an EMF.

Comment: @Majte Worth noting that an EMF file exported from Inkscape with convert text to paths disabled, and then inserted into a LibreOffice Impress document is editable, but you have to right click it and choose "Break" before you can edit it. I would assume that is like ungrouping the graphic. I don't use PowerPoint and don't know if it's possible in that software.

Comment: The solution has atually worked now. My bad, I had used a wrong filename and kept inserting the old one. My question is now to all Inkscape users, how can I disable the convert to textpath settings in the commanline version of Inkscape? I am on Almalinux.